# How to create a dynamic bar chart with in Bokeh?

Tags: javascript, python, data-visualization, bokeh

I want to create a dynamic bar chart in Bokeh. Basically I have *n* arrays, stored in a matrix (corresponding to words and frequencies), and I want to be able to choose which array to display (with a slider from *0* to *n*), and change the axis labels correspondingly.

When I try to reimplement https://demo.bokeh.org/sliders as a bar chart, the conversion between ColumnDataSource (for the callback) and Pandas Dataframe (for the bar chart) seems to break the callback.

The end result should be something vaguely similar to http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/chriddyp/9827cb5086cfab8da092/Pandas%20Widget%20-%20Time%20Series,%20Search,%20and%20Filtering.ipynb. Is this something that can be done in Bokeh? Am I better off using another non-Python service, like D3.js? IPython seems to be difficult for this case, but I'm open to anything.

Please advise?